# How to obtain a Facebook authentication token from a website

Tags: c#, facebook, social-networking

I'm relatively new to Facebook development and I've seen a lot of different information on authentication to Facebook but I'm wondering what the best way to do what I want to accomplish is. I'm creating a content-based website that I want to integrate with Facebook. On each content page will be a Facebook icon. When a user clicks on it, I want to use jQuery to open a small dialog that will allow the user to share a link to that page on their Facebook account and optionally enter a comment about it. If they have not authenticated to Facebook, it would display a login form and then once authenticated, display the form to post a link to their wall.

What I don't want to do at any point is redirect the user to Facebook.com for authentication (if that's possible). I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but I'd like to obtain an authentication token without them leaving the site and then store that token so that they don't have to log in to Facebook every time they want to share a link.

I'm really just trying to have a fully integrated authentication mechanism with my site so that I can sort of "link" a Facebook account to one of my user accounts and program against the Facebook API.

Like I said, I have very little knowledge of the Facebook API so I might be taking the wrong approach. Any suggestions on what the best way to create a fully integrated user experience would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this documentation page about [Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web). It will tell you how to do everything you seem to want. Though you have to have it redirect the user to facebook.com, but it would be in a new popup window (if you wanted it to be).

Comment: I'm aware of Facebook Connect but it presents a more "external" feel to the application. I'm really trying to go for a 100% integrated solution with my site, I just don't know if that's possible or not.

Comment: The user has to allow the application or web application access to their profile on Facebook - so no it technically is not possible.